# Cannot find hibernate configuration file when building Hibernate sessionFactory in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I have a simple project structure **[src][main][resouces]**
that is, the src folder has the main folder which has the resources folder and inside the resources folder, I have my hibernate.cfg.xml. Below are the files:

```
 hibernate.cfg.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- connection settings-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibTut</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!--connection pool size-->
        <property name = "connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- mapping resource -->
        <mapping resource= "user.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateManger.java class

```
public class HibernateSessionManager {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
            }
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, compiler complains that the "resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" is not found.

```
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Oct 11, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
Oct 11, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 11, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 11, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: ./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 11, 2015 12:36:45 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: ./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: ./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at tableSimulation.HibernateSessionManager.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionManager.java:33)
    at tableSimulation.HibernateSessionManager.<clinit>(HibernateSessionManager.java:11)
    at tableSimulation.Run.main(Run.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: ./resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
    at tableSimulation.HibernateSessionManager.buildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionManager.java:23)
```

Comment: I had a similar issue to this a while ago I finally got it working by moving the hibernate.cfg.xml file out of /resources and just put it within the /src folder and changed to just configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); may be worth a shot

Comment: @smoggers, that was the first try before I read a stack overflow saying that putting it in the resources folder might help. Unfortunately, both didn't help :(

Comment: yeah I'm not sure why its not finding it, having it in src/main/resources is the proper practice then you should just be able to do configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); as it is on the classpath

Comment: @smoggers
Ok, something strange is happening. I refactored the name of my configuration file to hiber.cfg.xml and when I ran it, I got this error which is strange given the name of the file is not hibernate.cfg.xml anymore:

...Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found...

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved now! I just changed this line **configuration.configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");**
to this :
**configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");**

and now it works.